# Body Type = Alpha Mask Scaling Issue Sprite Kit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am creating a Sprite Kit game were it's important for me to be able to exclude transparent parts of `SKNode` Textures when listening to "touches" (touchesbegan).

The solution that works for me is to set the physical body of the nodes to be
BodyType = Alpha mask.
In touches began method I can now iterate over all physicsbodies that are located in the point of the touch.

The **PROBLEM** now is that this works but the area of the masked body seems to be bigger then the actual size of the Node that but the shape of the body is correct.

Actually the physical body seems to be as big as the original image is before I set the node to be lets say half the size of the original image.
I have seen this behaviour previous in Sprite Kit.
My Scene in Interface Builder is 1024 points wide and I use AspectFill as the scaling option. What I can see is that if I print the scenes size its actually telling me 375 when running on the Iphone 6s (as the resolution of the iphone6s)

But e.g if I want a node to be wide as the screen I have to set it to 1024.
Can someone please help me understand this as it seems scaling problem.

Comment: You must provide some code to understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: You answered your own question, scaling a sprite does not scale the physics body,  try using SKAction.scale  I think this scales the body